# Optimization problem over two pages

Tags: align

I have written the optimization problem below. Here the ellipses represent several additional `rcases`. Since my optimization problem is so long, it does not fit on a single page and the last couple of constraints are not displayed at all.

Is there a way to write the problem so that is flows from one page to the next?

```
    \usepackage{amsfonts} 
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
\smash[b]{\underset{\substack{{x_{ij}\in\mathbb{R} \\ i=1,2,3 \\ j=1,\dots,4}}}{\textnormal{minimize}}} \quad
&4x_{11}+3x_{12}+10x_{13}+9x_{14}\\
&+9x_{21}+6x_{22}+13x_{23}+7x_{24}\\
&+12x_{31}+9x_{32}+16x_{33}+6x_{34}\\
\quad
 &\begin{rcases}
    \mathllap{\text{subject to} \quad}
    x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{13}+x_{14}\leq 30, \ \\
    x_{21}+x_{22}+x_{23}+x_{24}\leq 55, \ \\    
    x_{31}+x_{32}+x_{33}+x_{34}\leq 40, \ \\ 
      \end{rcases} (\text{supply constraints}) \\
    ...
    ...
    ...
      &\begin{rcases}
    -x_{11}-x_{21}-x_{31}\leq -40, \ \\ 
    -x_{12}-x_{22}-x_{32}\leq -25, \ \\ 
    -x_{13}-x_{23}-x_{33}\leq -30, \ \\ 
    -x_{14}-x_{24}-x_{34}\leq -30, \ \\ 
    \end{rcases} (\text{demand constraints}) \\
    &x_{ij}\geq 0, \ \ i=1,2,3, \ j=1,\dots,4\,. \ \   (\text{hidden constraints})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

With the ellipses removed (and only two `rcases` included), the optimization problem looks as follows.

[image]

Comment: Your code is both incomplete and with errors.  Please augment/correct.  Also, perhaps `\allowdisplaybreaks` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I forgot to add in the `mathtools` package, my apologies. If the ellipses are removed, the optimization problem will be displayed as the included image. I can remove the ellipses and add in the addtional 22 constraints, but this is quite lengthy. Should `\allowdisplayebreaks` be inserted where I'd like the break to occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the MWE is incomplete, the issue can be seen...  `equation*` cannot break across pages, but `amsmath` environments can, if `\allowdisplaybreaks` is set.  Thus, ditch the `equation*` environment, convert `aligned` into `align`, add `\notag` to each line to suppress equation numbers, and add `\allowdisplaybreaks` to the preamble.

EDIT: Thanks to Mico for suggesting to use `align*` instead of `align`.  In this way, the `\notag`s are not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\vspace*{6in}
%\begin{equation*}
\begin{align*}
%\smash[b]{\underset{\substack{{x_{ij}\in\mathbb{R} \\ i=1,2,3 \\ j=1,\dots,4}}}{\textnormal{minimize}}} \quad
&4x_{11}+3x_{12}+10x_{13}+9x_{14} \\
&+9x_{21}+6x_{22}+13x_{23}+7x_{24} \\
&+12x_{31}+9x_{32}+16x_{33}+6x_{34} \\
\quad
 &\begin{rcases}
    \mathllap{\text{subject to} \quad}
    x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{13}+x_{14}\leq 30, \ \\
    x_{21}+x_{22}+x_{23}+x_{24}\leq 55, \ \\    
    x_{31}+x_{32}+x_{33}+x_{34}\leq 40, \ \\ 
      \end{rcases} (\text{supply constraints})  \\
    ...
    ...
    ... \\
      &\begin{rcases}
    -x_{11}-x_{21}-x_{31}\leq -40, \ \\ 
    -x_{12}-x_{22}-x_{32}\leq -25, \ \\ 
    -x_{13}-x_{23}-x_{33}\leq -30, \ \\ 
    -x_{14}-x_{24}-x_{34}\leq -30, \ \\ 
    \end{rcases} (\text{demand constraints})  \\
    &x_{ij}\geq 0, \ \ i=1,2,3, \ j=1,\dots,4\,. \ \   (\text{hidden constraints})
\end{align*}
%\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Phenomenal, thank you! My optimization problem now flows between pages (it is nearly three pages long!)

Comment: +1. Since equation numers aren't needed, you could switch from an `align` to an `align*` environment, letting you omit all 14 `\notag` directives.

Comment: @mico Another brain burp.  I forgot.